# Twitter connectivity by asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I am working on twitter and getting problem when I want to get latest tweets from my account in my application I dont know what is the problem I think it may b dll problem 
here is my code

```
   string callbackUrl = "http://www.abc.com";
   string requestToken = OAuthUtility.GetRequestToken(consumerKey,consumerSecret,callbackUrl).Token;
   Session["RequestToken"] = requestToken;

   Uri authenticationUri = OAuthUtility.BuildAuthorizationUri(requestToken);
   AuthenticationUrlLink.Text = authenticationUri.AbsoluteUri;
   AuthenticationUrlLink.NavigateUrl = authenticationUri.AbsoluteUri;



    OAuthTokenResponse accessTokenResponse = OAuthUtility.GetAccessTokenDuringCallback(consumerKey, consumerSecret);
    string token=accessTokenResponse.Token;
    AccessTokenLabel.Text = accessTokenResponse.Token;
    AccessSecretLabel.Text = accessTokenResponse.TokenSecret;
    ScreenNameLabel.Text = accessTokenResponse.ScreenName;
    UserIdLabel.Text = accessTokenResponse.UserId.ToString();





    OAuthTokens tokens = new OAuthTokens()
    {
        AccessToken = xxxxxxxxxx,
        AccessTokenSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        ConsumerKey = xxxxxxxxxxxxx,
        ConsumerSecret = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    };

   TwitterResponse<TwitterUser> twitterResponse =witterAccount.VerifyCredentials(tokens);
```

When I hit last line  I got an error like null value
please healp me..
if dll problem please give me  I am unable to find it latest one on internet

Comment: `"I got an error like null value"` - Please, always give the exact, *full* error message.

Comment: Got errormessage=null and request.response=unknown

Comment: response.content= {"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]}

Comment: `string callbackUrl = "http://www.abc.com";` **http** should be **https**